# How to disable hideshow minor mode when editing?

Tags: code-folding, hideshow

I am trying to implement the following behavior: when hideshow minor mode is enabled and user start editing file (or alternatively pressed spacebar or enter key): automatically execute `hs-show-all` or just disable `hs-minor-mode`, - is there is a way to do that?

Idea is to use hideshow mode as some sort of navigation shortcut: on certain key execute `hs-hide-all`, then use arrow keys to navigate to desired portion of the document and automatically show all document when editing started. I will be happy to use other packages if similar functionality could be archived by other means. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the following function

```lisp
(defun hs-show-all-on-editing ()
  (unless (member last-command-event '(up down left right))
    (hs-show-all)
    (remove-hook 'pre-command-hook #'hs-show-all-on-editing)))
```

and then advise `hs-show-all` to add this function to the `pre-command-hook`:

```lisp
(advice-add 'hs-hide-all :after (lambda () (add-hook 'pre-command-hook #'hs-show-all-on-editing nil t)))
```

The logic in the function calls `hs-show-all` only when some other key than an arrow key is pressed, but you could add more 'keys' (that should not trigger `hs-show-all`) to the list.

Of course, this only works if you use `hs-hide-all` to hide the blocks (but you can always advise more functions).

If you'd like to use `SPC` or `RET` to trigger `hs-show-all` without inserting, then you could conditionally remove the inserted char using the `post-command-hook`:

```lisp
(defun hs-show-delete-backward-char ()
  (when (memq last-command-event '(13 32))
    (delete-backward-char 1)
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'hs-show-all-on-editing)))

(advice-add 'hs-hide-all :after (lambda () (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'hs-show-delete-backward-char nil t)))
```

Be aware that you should call `hs-hide-all` via a shortcut, because if you call it via `M-x` (which requires pressing `RET`) then this hook function will run directly after running `hs-hide-all`.

This is the most pragmatic solution. A better solution might be implemented by defining a minor mode, but this would require fully rewriting this answer, and as long as thing work fine, they work fine.

Although this idea does not seem bad at all, personally I am mostly using `imenu` (with helm/counsel/consult, i.e. `SPC j i` in Spacemacs) and 'evil marks' for quick navigation.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what i was looking for @dalanicolai ! - I have tried this solution but getting the following error: `condition-case: Invalid function: (hs-show-all-on-editing t)`, - thoughts?

Comment: Also, thank you for imenu tip, - i was not aware of this functionality, looking it up now...

Comment: ok, looks like using `(advice-add 'hs-hide-all :after
     '(lambda () (add-hook 'pre-command-hook #'hs-show-all-on-editing)))` fix the error. However there is one nuance: pressing space/enter still edit the text. So i tried to insert `undo` into `hs-show-all-on-editing` but this does not seems to work...

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah the advice-add definitely expects a function, don't know why I forgot to make it a lambda (lambda's are self-quoting b.t.w.). I thought using `SPC` or `RET` for executing `hs-show-all` was an 'alternative'. Anyway, I have 'extended' the answer.

Comment: Awesome - thank you very much @dalanicolai - this was very useful and educational! I have tried to replace `(delete-backward-char 1)` with `(undo)` but oddly enough _while working_ this produced message `Error in post-command-hook (hs-show-delete-backward-char): (user-error "No further undo information")` - any idea why? Thanks,